# having problems with importing variables from other files in the same folder.

Tags: python

Tried to import i Dictionary from another file in the same folder.

this is the "fluid" module:

```
fluiddensitydict = {
    "Acetone" : 791/1000,
    "Ammonia" :604/1000,
    "Benzene":879/1000,
    "Butane":556/1000,
    "CCL4":1584/1000,
    "CO2":680/1000,
    "Ethanol":783/1000,
    "Ethyl_Acetate":902/1000,
    "Gasoline":750/1000,
    "Glycerine":1260/1000,
    "Hexane":659/1000,
    "Honey":1417/1000,
    "Kerosene":815/1000,
    "Methanol":787/1000,
    "n_octane":692/1000,
    "Olive_Oil":910/1000,
    "Oil_engine":885/1000,
    "Oil_light":910/1000,
    "Pentane":626/1000,
    "Propane":510/1000,
    "R_twelve":1310/1000,
    "R_twentyTwo":1190/1000,
    "R_OneHundredThirtyFour_a":1206/1000,
    "Water":997/1000
}
```

Here is the "main" module:

```
import Fluid

for element in Fluid.fluiddensitydict():
    print(element)

FluidAnswer = input("\nWhich of these fluids would you like: ")

density = Fluid.fluiddensitydict.get(str(FluidAnswer))

for element in Fluid.fluiddensitydict():
    if element == FluidAnswer:
        print("your chosen fluid is ",element, "and it has the density 
:",density)
```

when i run the file i get the message:i get the error :
for element in Fluid.fluiddensitydict(): TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable

Comment: What is the name of the python file which has `Fluid` code?

Comment: That's because - well - dicts are not callable. Change ``Fluid.fluiddensitydict():`` to ``Fluid.fluiddensitydict:``

Comment: Anyway your loop seems pointless. You already have the density and the element name (in FluidAnswer).

Comment: The python file with the Fluid code is called Fluid.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fluiddensitydict` is already defined as a dictionary however you are calling as a function. You can iterate through both Keys and values and print the value of your dictionary which has the same key as your `input()` value: like this:

```
import Fluid
FluidAnswer = input("\nWhich of these fluids would you like: ")
for element, density in Fluid.fluiddensitydict.iteritems():
    if element == FluidAnswer:
        print("your chosen fluid is ",element, "and it has the density :",density)
```